# RadGrid collapsing upon sort

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, radgrid

I am new to the rad grid control and can't tell why the grid, which shows my results correctly keeps on collapsing when I sort it by any of its columns.

Here is my aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="temp.aspx.cs" Inherits="FEM.temp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/layout1.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FEM_ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <telerik:RadButton ID="rBtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="rBtnSearch_Click"></telerik:RadButton>

        <telerik:RadGrid ID="rGridPrograms" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True" GridLines="None"
          Visible="true" CssClass="MyGridClass">
            <MasterTableView ClientDataKeyNames="ColA,ColB,ColC" DataKeyNames="ColA,ColB,ColC">

                <Columns>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ColA" DataField="ColA" UniqueName="ColA" FilterControlWidth="30px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ColB" DataField="ColB" UniqueName="ColB" FilterControlWidth="30px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="ColC" DataField="ColC" UniqueName="ColC" FilterControlWidth="30px" AutoPostBackOnFilter="true">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="65px" />
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                </Columns>

            </MasterTableView>

        </telerik:RadGrid>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;

namespace FEM
{
    public partial class temp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        protected void rBtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select 1 as ColA, 2 as ColB, 3 as ColC Union select 4 as ColA, 5 as ColB, 6 as ColC";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  The post back was deleting the select command set by the Search button.